# jQuery datatables doesn't show titles

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to get dinamically tittles on jquery datatables from object, but it doesn't draw them.

For example, with this object:

```
var tableData = [ 
    { id: 1, user: 'admin', pass: 'pass', role: 'admin' },
    { id: 2, user: 'user', pass: 'pass', role: 'user' } 
]
```

this is my method:

```
function generateDatatable(tableId, tableData) {

    var columns = [];
    if (tableData.length == 0) {
        columns[0] = { data: '-' };
    } else {
        Object.keys(tableData[0]).forEach(element => {
            columns[columns.length] = { data: element };
        });
    }

    jQuery('#' + tableId).DataTable({
        data: tableData,
        language: dataTablesTexts,
        pagingType: 'full',
        lengthMenu: [
            [10, 25, 50, -1], 
            [10, 25, 50, 'All']
        ],
        searching: true,
        ordering:  true,
        paging: true,
        select: false,
        info: true,
        responsive: true,
        columns: columns
    });

}
```

I can see the values but not the tittles.

Resultant columns will look like this:

```
var columns = [
    {data: "id"},
    {data: "user"},
    {data: "pass"},
    {data: "role"}
]
```

if I change `data: "..."` to `title: "..."` I can see the titles but not the values.

What could be wrong with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use both: [`data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) to point to specific property within data source that corresponds to current column for each entry and [`title`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.title) to specify column title.

Comment: oh I thought that will gets it authomatically. It works fine with columns[columns.length] = { data: element, title: element}; lots of thanks